# Node js can't upload files to FTP when deployed and running on production server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, ftp, digital-ocean

I'm using Node JS (12.13.0) and NPM (6.13.19) with [basic-ftp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/basic-ftp). Everything works fine and I can upload files to the remote FTP (without SSL, my remote FTP doesn't allow this) when I run the code on my development machine from localhost.

The production server is hosted on Digital Ocean (Ubuntu 18.04.3) I have tried to disable the firewall, because I thought this might be the reason to the problem. I used `sudo ufw disable` and just to make sure it's disabled I check the current status with `sudo ufw status` which returns `Status: inactive`.

This is my code

```
async function uploadImageToFtp(fileName, path) {
    const client = new ftp.Client()
    client.ftp.verbose = true
    try {
        await client.access({
            host: process.env.FTP_HOST,
            user: process.env.FTP_USER,
            password: process.env.FTP_PASSWORD,
            secure: false
        })
        await client.uploadFrom(path, "images/bd/" + fileName)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    client.close()
}
```

Response on production

```
Connected to EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS < 220 server ready - login please Login
security: No encryption
> USER username < 331 password required
> PASS ###
```

Again on localhost everything works and we get past this step and starts uploading the file(s) to the same server and credentials.

After this I never get any response, except for a timeout with Bad Gateway 502 from my request.

Comment: Try to change secure to true !

Comment: Then I'll get 220 server ready - login please
> AUTH TLS
< 530 login first
FTPError: 530 login first - But again, my remote FTP doesn't allow secure login, so this isn't a possibility :-)

Comment: Are you using this npm package :https://github.com/mscdex/node-ftp

Comment: No, I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/basic-ftp :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the library, but the problem sounds like the FTP session is running in active mode. That can often be a problem, so if it is in active mode, I'd recommend trying setting your client to ask for passive mode.

Comment: According to basic-ftp it already runs on passive mode. But the transactions are handled AFTER the PASS, which mean my production server never gets to this call.

Answer (score 0):

There is issue with AWS dynamic routing. your instance is under vpc and nat is not able to resolve the address back from ftp server to your instance.

You can try by adding route entry in ip table. [Check here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ip-route-add-network-command-for-linux-explained/)

This tells the nat to resolve particular ftp to specific address. i hope this will help.